# PHP Recordset Paging, changing url Parameter

Tags: php, url, paging

Bit of a newby to PHP & Mysql, and mainly use Dreamweavers inbuilt functions, but am trying to get my hands dirty and understand what things do a little more and subsequently fix a couple of problems.

I have a file (search.php) which when viewed has two URL parameters '`letter`' and '`search`' so I get `'search.php?letter=A&search=no'`

Within the body of the page, I have a recordset paging function (from Dreamweaver). When using the paging, I end up with a URL similar to this

```
'search.php?pageNum_results_empty=1&totalRows_results_empty=2937&letter=A&search=no'
```

Very simply all I want to do is change the parameter '`search`' from '`no`' to '`yes`'. From what I can work out, I need to remove '`search=no`' from the query string, and then add '`search=yes`' to the link. I'm not just not able to remove it from the query string, or am I barking up the wrong tree.

Any advice gratefully received

**PHP Code**

```
$isSearch = $_GET['search'];

$queryString_results_empty = "";
if (!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
  $newParams = array();
  foreach ($params as $param) {
    if (stristr($param, "pageNum_results_empty") == false && 
        stristr($param, "totalRows_results_empty") == false) {
      array_push($newParams, $param);
    }
  }
  if (count($newParams) != 0) {
    $queryString_results_empty = "&" . htmlentities(implode("&", $newParams));
  }
}
$queryString_results_empty = sprintf("&totalRows_results_empty=%d%s", $totalRows_results_empty, $queryString_results_empty);
```

**Link Recordset Paging Code**

```
<?php if ($pageNum_results_empty < $totalPages_results_empty) { // Show if not last page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_results_empty=%d%s", $currentPage, min($totalPages_results_empty, $pageNum_results_empty + 1), $queryString_results_empty); ?>">
        <img src="images/arrow-next.png" width="58" height="97" alt=""/>
        </a>
        <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str_replace('search=no','search=yes',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```